# $\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n=+\infty\ \mathrm{a.s.}$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}S_n=-\infty\ \mathrm{a.s.}$ for the random walk $(S_n)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be i.i.d. real-valued random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(X_1)=0$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_1)=\mathbb{E}({X_1}^2)>0$, where the variance $\mathrm{Var}(X_1)$ can be $+\infty$. Let $(S_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a random walk of $(X_n)$, i.e.
$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k.$$
Note that the expectation and variance of $S_n$ is
$$\mathbb{E}(S_n)=0,\qquad \mathrm{Var}(S_n)=\mathbb{E}({S_n}^2)=n\mathrm{Var}(X_1)=n\mathbb{E}({X_1}^2)>0.$$
Then I want to prove the following:
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n=+\infty\quad \mathrm{a.s.}\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad\liminf_{n\to\infty}S_n=-\infty\quad \mathrm{a.s.}$$
In my attempt, I considerd $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ separately. First, we get
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n>\varepsilon\right)=0\quad \mathrm{or}\quad 1$$
for any $\varepsilon>0$ from the Kolmogorov's 0–1 law. If that value is $0$, then we have
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n\leq\varepsilon\right)=1$$
i.e.
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n\leq\varepsilon\quad \mathrm{a.s.}$$
Thus
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n\leq0\quad \mathrm{a.s.}\tag{1}$$
by $\varepsilon\to+0$. Also, from the Fatou's lemma, we obtain
$$0=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(S_n)\leq\mathbb{E}\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n\right)\leq0.$$
Therefore $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n=0$ a.s. because of (1).

My proof is stopped here. I want to lead a contradiction by using $\mathrm{Var}(S_n)\to +\infty$, but I don't know the concrete idea. Would someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use Kolmogorov's 0-1 law because the $\{ \limsup S_n\ > \varepsilon \}$ is not a tail event.

Comment: @CélioAugusto oh really?

Comment: Yep. Note that the value of the r.v. $X_1$ affects the value of $\limsup S_n$. The event $\{ \limsup S_n/n > \varepsilon \}$ is a tail event though, maybe this would help. But the way I would prove the result is using Martingale Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @CélioAugusto Can we use not Kolmogorov but Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law? This theorem says $\mathbb{P}(\limsup S_n>\varepsilon)\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Everyone, I have solved this question.